# Хочу добавить в игру "змейка" дополнительное яблочко, которое даёт больше очков, появляется в случайный момент времени и убираться

Tags: python-3.x

Хочу добавить в игру "змейка" дополнительное яблочко, которое даёт больше очков, появляется в случайный момент времени и убираться через несколько секунд. Как создать я знаю, а вот как убрать яблочко через несколько секунд и как его показать пользователю в случайное время без понятия?
Основа этот код P.S извенюсь я новичок.
[Код в файле][1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ndZcBBF8jYyjW8D1-yvyk8uKNuTcktS/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Опубликуйте свой код в вопросе -  Goole Диск Требуется разрешение

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в игре есть таймер, на шаге которого змейка делает шаг. Там и втавь `if random() < 0.01:` после этого рисуй яблочко и сохрани время в переменную. Провеяряй это время на каждом шаге и когда будет нужно убирай.